# Loading labels from Python script in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, labeling, qgis-3

Is there a way to add labels of the added layers using python. I've tried these lines of code but no label shows after execution in **QGIS 3.0**

```
for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fieldName", "Id" )
    layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/placement", QgsPalLayerSettings.Horizontal)
    layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/predefinedPointPosition", QgsPalLayerSettings.BottomRight)
    layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fontSize","10" )
    layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/bufferDraw", True)
    layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/enabled","true" )
    layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After surfing the platform. Found the following working solution;

```
for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    layer_settings  = QgsPalLayerSettings()
    text_format = QgsTextFormat()

    text_format.setFont(QFont("Arial", 12))
    text_format.setSize(12)

    buffer_settings = QgsTextBufferSettings()
    buffer_settings.setEnabled(True)
    buffer_settings.setSize(0.10)
    buffer_settings.setColor(QColor("black"))

    text_format.setBuffer(buffer_settings)
    layer_settings.setFormat(text_format)

    layer_settings.fieldName = "Id"
    layer_settings.placement = 4

    layer_settings.enabled = True

    layer_settings = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(layer_settings)
    layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
    layer.setLabeling(layer_settings)
    layer.triggerRepaint()
```