# How to set background color of label using PyQGIS 3?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

suppose I have a shapefile that have an attribute, and I want that attribute to be shown with white background behind the text in the viewport.

This is what I want to accomplish:

[image: labels with white background]

I've searched the internet and tried this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/277111/51131 but it only shows the labels without the background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only a slight adjustment was  required to the code posted already (on  https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/277111/51131):

```
for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    layer_settings  = QgsPalLayerSettings()
    text_format = QgsTextFormat()
    background_color = QgsTextBackgroundSettings()

    background_color.setFillColor(QColor('white'))
    background_color.setEnabled(True)

    text_format.setFont(QFont("Arial", 12))
    text_format.setSize(12)
    text_format.setBackground(background_color )

    buffer_settings = QgsTextBufferSettings()
    buffer_settings.setEnabled(True)
    buffer_settings.setSize(0.10)
    buffer_settings.setColor(QColor("black"))

    text_format.setBuffer(buffer_settings)
    layer_settings.setFormat(text_format)

    layer_settings.fieldName = "Label"
    layer_settings.placement = 4

    layer_settings.enabled = True

    layer_settings = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(layer_settings)
    layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
    layer.setLabeling(layer_settings)
    layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Make sure to upgrade to the newest QGIS version (3.2). Instantiating the QgsTextBackgroundSettings class does not seem to function properly in 3.0.

Comment: Thank you, it's working. Where do you learn this from?

Comment: You welcome! Essentially I had a look at the QGIS Python API, and what is the way to set a background to the QgsTextFormat object. Have a look here: https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/Text/QgsTextFormat.html#qgis.core.QgsTextFormat.background

Comment: How did you know if it had to be set enabled to True? How to use RGB color code instead of color's name?

Comment: Under the method 'enabled' for the QgsTextBackgroundSettings, it says: enabled(self) → bool. To use RGB, simply pass RGB arguments instead of the name to the QColor class. Example: QColor(0,255,0) for green.