# Display labels set from within QgsProcessingAlgorithm in QGIS 3.x?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, labeling, qgis-processing

I'm writing a simple `QgsProcessingAlgorithm` and I need to set some labels (to display the azimuths of the sides of a polygon).
I can set the labeling expression alright (the expression is properly set and after the `QgsProcessingAlgorithm` has run, if I open the properties dialog and simply click OK, the correct labels will be shown) but can't get it to display automatically.
I've commented some lines that I thought could do the trick but don't seem to do anything actually.

```
def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
    source = self.parameterAsSource(parameters, self.INPUT, context)

    outputs = {}
    results = {}

    #Polygons to Lines
    alg_params = {
        'INPUT': parameters['INPUT'],
        'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
    }
    outputs['PolygonsToLines'] = processing.run('native:polygonstolines', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

    #Explode Lines
    alg_params = {
        'INPUT': outputs['PolygonsToLines']['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT': parameters['OUTPUT']
    }
    outputs['ExplodeLines'] = processing.run('native:explodelines', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

    results['OUTPUT'] = outputs['ExplodeLines']['OUTPUT']

    layer = QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString(results['OUTPUT'], context)

    pls = QgsPalLayerSettings()
    pls.isExpression = True
    pls.fieldName = 'CONCAT(format_number(degrees(azimuth(start_point($geometry), end_point($geometry))) % 180, 2), \'°\')'
    #pls.enabled = True
    layer.setLabeling(QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(pls))
    layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
    #layer.commitChanges()
    #layer.triggerRepaint()

    return results
```

EDIT:
Although I'm primarily interested in solving the problem for the `QgsProcessingAlgorithm`, it is worth noting that after running the two algorithms manually, executing the following code (after selecting the `Exploded` layer) in the `python console` doesn't work either.

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()

pls = QgsPalLayerSettings()
pls.isExpression = True
pls.fieldName = 'CONCAT(format_number(degrees(azimuth(start_point($geometry), end_point($geometry))) % 180, 2), \'°\')'
pls.enabled = True

layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
layer.setLabeling(QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(pls))
#layer.labeling()

#layer.commitChanges()
#layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Comment: I think it's because the layer is only loaded when the line `return results` is executed. Before this, the layer is not loaded and so applying any labelling or styling will not work. I have had similar issues with this and tried workarounds such as loading the layer manually with `QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)` before the `return` statement but unfortunately it doesn't help.

Comment: I've tried to do the styling from the python console but label still don't show, so there must be something else.

Comment: How did you define `layer` in the console?

Comment: I ran the two algorithms manually so the 'exploded' layer is already loaded. I have `layer = iface.activeLayer()` (not sure of the exact syntax, I'm not in front of the computer)

Comment: You console code works for me if you uncomment `layer.triggerRepaint()`. Which QGIS 3 version are you using? I tested this on 3.8.2.

Comment: I'm on 3.8.3 and it still doesn't work for me :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/277111/30694), I've tried adding a `placement` value to the `QgsPalLayerSettings` and it works.
The commented lines aren't needed in the `QgsAlgorithm`.

```
pls = QgsPalLayerSettings()
pls.isExpression = True
pls.fieldName = 'CONCAT(format_number(degrees(azimuth(start_point($geometry), end_point($geometry))) % 180, 2), \'°\')'
pls.placement = QgsPalLayerSettings.Placement.Line

layer.setLabeling(QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(pls))
layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
```